# $state.go() is not working properly because its loading previous cached data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

`$state.go()` is not working properly because its loading previous cached data..

I have tried it via several ways like,

```
  $state.go('main.page', {reload: 'main.page', cache: false}); //reload given pg
  $state.go('main.page', {reload: true, cache: false}); //go & reload given pg
  $state.go('main.page');                          // go & with reload 
  $state.go('main.page', {reload: true});    //  etc. many more ways
```

but still its loading previous data on Webpage... As well as I have also tried 
 `$state.transitionTo()` by many ways but couldn't get any positive outcome...

`'main.page'` this webPage should load with current values from the back-end I have to specifically reload/refresh that page to get latest values...

`$state.go()` is not working properly because its loading previous cached data..